# Custom Postgresql Function Constraint with Percentage of Row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named user_address that joins a user table and an address table.  The user_address table has a percent_ownership column.  I wanted to constrain the total percent_ownership for each address_id to be 100(%) but in order to do this the function would have to total the existing percentage ownership for the address id in the table.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: This is trickier than it sounds.  It means that you cannot update one row without updating all rows for an address.  You cannot delete one row either -- without updating all other rows.  You might want to rethink the data model.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How about checking all rows of the address_id first to see the existing ownership amount and then the new percent_ownership would constrain a combined total of 100(%).  I don't need to change other rows based on the new row.  I just don't want the total percent_ownership for the address_id to be greater than 100.

Comment: @sandman . . . I'm just saying that what you are asking for is tricky and will affect, `insert`s, `update`s, and `delete`s on the table.  I have ideas on how to solve your *problem*.  But you have already specified a particular solution in the form of a function.  Even if you have such a function, there may be unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could instead add a `weight` column that specifies the relative weight of each share. The exact percentage is then calculated when you `SELECT` from the table.

For example, if all the weights are equal, everybody has an equal share. If the weight of one user is twice the weight of another user, the calculated percentage will be twice as high.

The advantage of such a model is that you don't have to modify other rows whenever one row changes.